# Pseudo class :first-letter doesn't except display:block or position absolute

Tags: css

I have an issue, I want to put the first letter in the first raw separate from the text, It seems that CSS isn't recognize display:block; or position:absolute to pseudo class of first-letter.

note: I can't add another tag to the first letter.

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/dPvNdR)

**HTML**

```
<div class="some-word">
  Product
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.some-word:first-letter{
  font-size:30px;
  display:block; /**doesnt work**/
  position:absolute;/**doesnt work**/
}
```

That's what I try to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Solution Found

First Solution
To add to the wrapper element **word-break:all;** + add to the first letter margin-right:100%; + add some width to the word container;

[VIEW EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/OPpWGr)

```
.some-word{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:70px;
  word-break: break-all; 
}

.some-word:first-letter{
  font-size:30px;
  margin-right:100%;  
}
```

Second Solution
add to the first-letter **float:left;** + margin-right:100%; + add some width to the word container;

[VIEW EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/OPpWGr)

```
.some-word{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:70px;  
}

.some-word:first-letter{
  font-size:30px;
  margin-right:100%;  
  float:left;
}
```

from this place I can continue,
Alex Char, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look to [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#Summary):

Only a small subset of all CSS properties can be used inside a declaration block of a CSS ruleset containing a selector using the ::first-letter pseudo-element:

- All font properties : font, font-style, font-feature-settings, font-kerning, font-language-override, font-stretch, font-synthesis, font-variant, font-variant-alternates, font-variant-caps, font-variant-east-asian, font-variant-ligatures, font-variant-numeric, font-variant-position, font-weight, font-size, font-size-adjust, line-height and font-family.
- All background properties : background-color, background-image, background-clip, background-origin, background-position, background-repeat, background-size, background-attachment, and background-blend-mode.
- All margin properties: margin, margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom, margin-left.
- All padding properties: padding, padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, padding-left.
- All border properties: the shorthands border, border-style, border-color, border-width, border-radius, border-image, and the longhands properties.
- The color property
- The text-decoration, text-shadow, text-transform, letter-spacing,
  word-spacing (when appropriate), line-height, text-decoration-color,
  text-decoration-line, text-decoration-style, box-shadow, float,
  vertical-align (only if float is none) CSS properties.

As this list will be extended in the future, **it is recommended that you not use any other properties inside the declaration block**, in order to keep the CSS future-proof.

Now for your problem if you can change your html structure you can use a `span` for the first letter  and style it as you like. For example:

```css
.some-word span {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-word">
  <span>P</span>roduct
</div>
```

Comment: I can't add another tag to the first letter. the text come dynamic

Comment: Is it allowed to use javascript?

Answer (score 2):

*The first-letter did-not have Position property*
So That if you want to move your first-letter without using any other element like span in your code, you can use "margin property"

```css
div {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 20px 25px 20px 35px;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}

div::first-letter {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 9px 7px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
  <div>1 Hello, Welcome To Elzero Web School</div>
```